# constructor error creating new Karel right turn robot

Tags: java, constructor, awt, karel

I'm new to java and trying to create a new robot class with a method for Karel to turn right. However, when I try and extend the class "RightTurnerRobot" to include "Robot", I get the following error:

> Implicit super constructor Robot() is undefined for default
>   constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

My code is below, any help is appreciated.

```
import kareltherobot.*; 
import kareltherobot.Robot;

import java.awt.*; 

public class RightTurnerRobot extends Robot implements RobotTask
{

 public void TurnRight()
 {
  turnLeft();
  turnLeft();
  turnLeft();
 }

 static
 {
   World.setDelay(100); 

   World.setSize(10, 10);
 }

  public void task()
  { 
    //World.readWorld("src", "someworldname.kwld");

    UrRobot grace = new UrRobot(3, 3, East, 30);
    grace.move();
    grace.turnOff();
  }
```

Edit: I figured out the problem. It was supposed to extend `UrRobot` instead of `Robot`. Then I made a constructor with:

```
import kareltherobot.*; //Needed for Robots

import java.awt.*; //Needed for Color
public class RightTurnerRobot extends UrRobot
{
  public RightTurnerRobot(int street, int avenue, Direction direction,
    int beepers)
  {
    super(street, avenue, direction, beepers);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }

  public void turnRight()
  {
    turnLeft();
    turnLeft();
    turnLeft();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you put the `Robot` class here?

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha its an Library look up kareltherobot.

Comment: Why post Robot? It is a standard Java class. unless, of course, the OP has created his own Robot class. Which now I see is the case. So that Robot class probably does not have a no-argument constructor.

Comment: can you try this

public RightTurnerRobot () {
    super();
}
and tell me if you get an error.

Comment: @BSD_ Sorry, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha check my answer.

Comment: check edit! Please. @ImeshaSudasingha

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a constructor matching the Robot class because you are extending it.

```
import kareltherobot.*; 
import kareltherobot.Robot;

import java.awt.*; 

public class RightTurnerRobot extends Robot implements RobotTask
{

public RightTurnerRobot(int arg0, int arg1, Direction arg2, int arg3) {
    super(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
}

public void TurnRight()
{
 turnLeft();
 turnLeft();
 turnLeft();
}

static
{
 World.setDelay(100); 

 World.setSize(10, 10);
}

public void task()
 { 
//World.readWorld("src", "someworldname.kwld");

UrRobot grace = new UrRobot(3, 3, East, 30);
grace.move();
grace.turnOff();
}
```

In my opinion though a better way to do this is like this.

```
import kareltherobot.*;
import kareltherobot.Robot;

import java.awt.*;

public class RobotWorld{

    //Create Robot
    Robot robot;

    public RobotWorld () {
        //Initialize World
        World.readWorld("PATH/TO/WORLD");
        World.setVisible(true);

        //Initialize Robot
        robot = new Robot(3, 3, Robot.East, 3);
        turnRight(robot);
    }

    public void turnRight (Robot tempRobot) {
        tempRobot.turnLeft();
        tempRobot.turnLeft();
        tempRobot.turnLeft();
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        RobotWorld world = new RobotWorld();
    }
}
```